# How can I interrupt IMAP's IDLE?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-mail

I am using the Javamail API connecting to my IMAP server. Everything is working great with the javax.mail.Folder.idle() [method](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#idle()). My listener gets called when a new mail comes in. However the problem is idle blocks forever, how do I interrupt it? How do I actually stop the listening without killing my Java program?

I've tried calling Thread.interrupt() on the idle'd thread. Nothing happens. I am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Performing any operation on that folder (from another thread) will cause `idle()` method to return immediately. So if you want to forcefully interrupt it, just call `close()` from a new thread.

Answer (score 4):

If you read the documentation properly, and read the source code, you'll realise that you have to create a new thread for calling `.idle()`.

Allocate that thread to a variable, and whenever you want call the `interrupt()` on that thread, or just ignore notifications!

If you need to get `idle()` going again, just rerun the thread!

I created something similar, so you might wanna check it out.

https://github.com/mofirouz/JavaPushMail/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mofirouz/javapushmail/JavaPushMailAccount.java

Good luck

Comment: I would vote for this answer as it's simple, yet accurate and informative, I was kind of thinking of the possibility of using an external thread for idling, but kind of thought that it would be ugly from design, well I guess it has to be ugly when it comes to multithreading and similar things. So to sum up, this solution works great, I was too lazy to thoroughly analyze the example in the link, but I tested according to this post and I can confirm it works great, haven't noticed any drawbacks so far.

Answer (score 0):

A proper way to abort IDLE command is the following snippet. Note that the Folder instance should be the same as the one used to start idling. I've tested the other solutions proposed on this thread but they didn't work in my case.

```
IMAPFolder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
try {
  folder.doOptionalCommand("Abort IDLE error mesage", new IMAPFolder.ProtocolCommand() {
  @Override
  public Object doCommand(IMAPProtocol p) throws ProtocolException {
    p.idleAbort();
    return Boolean.TRUE;
  }
});
} catch (MessagingException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Did you just answer a 9 year old that has an accepted answer?

Comment: Obviously yes since I spent 1 day trying to figure out why the proposed answer do not work.