# How can I get the notification when email came with Gmail-api

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Is there an api I can to figure out the notification likes email came?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As gmail server supports IDLE, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424003/right-way-to-poll-gmail-inbox-for-incoming-mail-from-stand-alone-application

Answer (score 0):

Use push notification provided by gmail, following is the link 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push
Please go through it.

Comment: Add something from the page as you found it usable. Please don't just post the link as an answer.