# Downloading a site's content and displaying (part of) it in another site

Tags: javascript, java, automation

I want to make a program that logs into some sites, say Gmail, some news site, etc. Make it download some of the content (important emails, for example), and show it in some site I make.

Can this be done with Java? If not, is there any 'simple' way to do this with JavaScript (I'm just a noobie at it)?

Thanks.

Comment: We need more specific questions. What you wrote is very abstract. You can do this in hundreds of programming languages, but it's important to know exactly from where you are going to fetch the content and its availability (i.e. for gmail you need to authenticate for example) and formats in order to parse it later. You can do this in java yes (making some HTTP request to fetch the data from some services) and if you like javascript (node.js is easiest to do what you want).

Comment: you will need to investigate the APIs that are available for each service.

Comment: Can this be done with Java? Yes. Can it be done with JavaScript? Yes. Explaining how would take pages and pages. StackOverflow is well-suited for answering specific, concrete questions, not broad hypotheticals. See the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide for more.

Answer (score 0):

There is! Try this:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    properties.put("mail.imaps.host", "imap.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.imaps.port", "993");
    properties.put("mail.imaps.timeout", "10000");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties); 
    IMAPStore store = null;
    Folder inbox = null;

    try {
        store = (IMAPStore) session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect(username, password);
        ...
```

This connects to gmail using IMAP.

If you want to know more, this question is great: [Right way to display mail from Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424003/right-way-to-poll-gmail-inbox-for-incoming-mail-from-stand-alone-application)