# How to set timeout for IMAPFolder.idle

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jakarta-mail

I'm implementing Webdriver test with java including checking email from Gmail. My code is here:

```
public static void checkNewEmail(String user, String password, String sender, String subject, ArrayList<String> errorList) throws MessagingException {
    boolean result = false;
    Store store = null;
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.timeout", "10000");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.connectiontimeout", "10000");

    try {

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        store = session.getStore();
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", user, password);
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        //add listener
        System.out.println("Listening for New message");
        final Message[] email = new Message[1];
        inbox.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {
                Message[] messages = ev.getMessages();
                for (Message msg : messages) {
                    //process emails here
                    System.out.println("New message");
                    email[0] = msg;
                }
            }
        });
        ((IMAPFolder) inbox).idle(true);

        if(email[0] != null) {
            if (email[0].getFrom()[0].toString().contains(sender) && email[0].getSubject().contains(subject)) {
                gm.printSuccessMsg("===PASSED: Correct email arrived.");
                result = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect email arrived.");
                System.out.println(email[0].getFrom()[0].toString());
                System.out.println(email[0].getSubject());
                if (store != null) {
                    store.close();
                }
                checkNewEmail(user, password, sender, subject, errorList);
            }
        }

    } catch (FolderClosedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (store != null) {
            store.close();
        }

    } finally {
        if(!result)
            errorList.add("Store email");
        if (store != null) {
            store.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Debug output:

```
    DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "imap.gmail.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 103.248.166.14 y22mb380918775jaq
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN AUTH=OAUTHBEARER AUTH=XOAUTH
A0 OK Thats all she wrote! y22mb380918775jaq
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: OAUTHBEARER
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=imap.gmail.com, user=nobia.bada.sigdal@gmail.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 OK nobia.bada.sigdal@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
A2 ENABLE UTF8=ACCEPT
* ENABLED UTF8=ACCEPT
A2 OK Success
DEBUG IMAPS: connection available -- size: 1
A3 EXAMINE INBOX
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] Flags permitted.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1] UIDs valid.
* 618 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDNEXT 817] Predicted next UID.
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 69350]
A3 OK [READ-ONLY] INBOX selected. (Success)
Listening for New message
A4 IDLE
+ idling
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: set to IDLE
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: return true
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: ignoring socket timeout
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: ignoring socket timeout
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: ignoring socket timeout
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: ignoring socket timeout
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: ignoring socket timeout
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: ignoring socket timeout
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: ignoring socket timeout
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: ignoring socket timeout
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: ignoring socket timeout
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: ignoring socket timeout
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: ignoring socket timeout
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: ignoring socket timeout
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: ignoring socket timeout
....
```

When there is a correct email arriving, it can check and terminate the listener properly. But when there is no incoming email, it keeps waiting forever, and the timeout does not seem to work and it's hanging in `DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: ignoring socket timeout`. Is anyone having the same issue ? I've tried changing from "setProperty" to "put" (using int instead of string) but it's still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [IMAPFolder source](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/blob/38da59413d50f0946127974116ef927c8e7aa210/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.java#L3224):

```
/*
 * If it was a timeout and no bytes were transferred
 * we ignore it and go back and read again.
 * If the I/O was otherwise interrupted, and no
 * bytes were transferred, we take it as a request
 * to abort the IDLE.
 */
```

So setting the timeout doesn't cause IDLE to abort.  If you want [IDLE to abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326014/how-can-i-interrupt-imaps-idle) create another thread to wait for a deadline and call close when the deadline has expired.